# Top bar missing on my laptop

Tags: interface

I tried blender on my laptop, the top of the window seem to be cut, and i can't see every tool especially taskbar which's supposed to be there.
That's not such a big problem but the real problem is that the cursor is copletly off when i try to click on something the cursor actually goes way higher than what i was aiming for.

The white cross is actually where my cursor is supposed to be and you can see the taskbar is missing up there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most display related errors, or missing elements on the interface, are caused by the drivers for your GPU (graphics card).

Try a different version of the driver. Sometimes upgrading helps, sometimes you have to go to an older version.