# Why do i not have Add button beside the File button?

Tags: modeling

Why do I not have a Add button beside the File button in the top menu?
When ever I watch a tutorial I never have any of the same buttons and it doesn't seem to matter what file version of Blender I'm using.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add an image of what the interface looks like in your computer.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107907/top-bar-missing-on-my-laptop or maybe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69337/how-to-show-accidentally-hidden-menu-bar or maybe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an add button next to file either. It's probably a custom layout that they have.

Blender is all about shortcuts. Using shortcuts will allow you to work faster than you could in any other software so use Shift + A to add objects in object mode and in edit mode. Let me know if this works for you.